# Row Number is not allowed under MySQL 8 ver

Tags: mariadb, window-functions, mariadb-10.1

Could someone help me create an SQL query that could work below MySQL 8. Currently, this query is working on my localhost but when transferred to the Live was showing an error.

This query scores the racers from 10 to 1 (1st place = 10pts, 10th place = 1point) that runs automatically on Monday Midnight.

Here's the sample table:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_race_has_list` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `group_name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `timer` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `weekly_score`  SMALLINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

$sql = "UPDATE tbl_race_has_list
    INNER JOIN 
    (
            SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by timer ASC) AS RacerRank
            FROM tbl_race_has_list
            WHERE DATE(created)
                BETWEEN DATE_SUB(DATE(now()), INTERVAL (WEEKDAY(now()) - 1 + 7) % 7 DAY)
                AND DATE_ADD(DATE(now()), INTERVAL 6 - (WEEKDAY(now()) - 1 + 7) % 7 DAY)
            ORDER BY timer ASC LIMIT 0, 10
    ) c
        ON racerTime.tbl_race_has_list.id = c.id
    SET racerTime.tbl_race_has_list.weekly_score = 11 - c.RacerRank";
```

**Update**. I created an SQL query that could work below MySQL 8 ver. It is working as intended but I am open to a better approach.

```
UPDATE tbl_race_has_list
    INNER JOIN 
    (
            SELECT *, (@row_number := @row_number + 1) AS RacerRank
            FROM tbl_race_has_list
            (SELECT @row_number := 0) AS x
            WHERE DATE(created)
                BETWEEN DATE_SUB(DATE(now()), INTERVAL (WEEKDAY(now()) - 1 + 7) % 7 DAY)
                AND DATE_ADD(DATE(now()), INTERVAL 6 - (WEEKDAY(now()) - 1 + 7) % 7 DAY)
            ORDER BY timer ASC LIMIT 0, 10
    ) c
        ON racerTime.tbl_race_has_list.id = c.id
    SET racerTime.tbl_race_has_list.weekly_score = 11 - c.RacerRank
```

Comment: I think that's in the title, as ROW_NUMBER() was introduced in MySQL 8.

Comment: Once you run this query on Live PHPmyadmin. Here's the error:  Error in query (1064): Syntax error near '(order by timer ASC) AS RacerRank FROM tbl_race_has_list WHERE DATE(creat' at line 1)

Comment: To the OP: incompatibilities between dev and prod major versions of MySQL have far more extended consequences than just missing ROW_NUMBER func. You'll have to sync those: either by upgrading the prod DB (and yes, I know that's a daunting task) or  by downgrading the one used in development.

Comment: I doubt you are using MySQL 8. Maybe you are using a MySQL 8 _client_, but the error you describe would indicate your MySQL Server is not MySQL 8, and that's the important part for SQL support. Can you please run `SELECT VERSION();` and report the result?

Comment: @raina77ow I can't uprade or downgrade the prod DB since the server was for our magento site and this is project where I am having issues is  just a microsite I am developing.

Comment: @BillKarwin prod DB shows this result: 10.1.48-MariaDB-1~stretch and my localhost with this: 10.4.19-MariaDB

Comment: Whoever is in charge of that production server should look out for upgrades. That version of MariaDB is pretty old, and the regular support for Debian Stretch has ended one year ago

Answer (score 2):

The code you showed at the start of your question should work fine in MySQL 8.0.

But we learned in the comment thread above that you are not using MySQL at all, you are using MariaDB. MariaDB is not MySQL. It forked from MySQL in 2010 and has been growing more incompatible gradually since then. We should think of MariaDB as a different product now, not a drop-in replacement for MySQL as they once claimed.

On your production server, you are using a MariaDB 10.1, which is too old to support window functions. See their documentation: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/window-functions/

> Window functions were first introduced in MariaDB 10.2.0.

It's a good habit to make sure your development environment has the exact same versions of all components of your complete technology stack. Otherwise you risk exactly what happened in this case, you develop some code that relies on newer features, and then find that the code doesn't work when you deploy to production.

You should insist that your production server gets updated. MariaDB 10.1 passed its end of life in October 2020, according to https://endoflife.date/mariadb.

Failing that, try to find a version of MariaDB 10.1 to install in your development. That might take some creative searching, because 10.1 has been removed from the official download site: https://mariadb.com/downloads/